# Why is my program printing an extra new line in my file?

Tags: c

I've attached a photo of what my code is doing. It's supposed to print one word per line with no extra new lines. I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I just can't figure out what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
 
int main (){
    freopen("The Parsnip.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int repeat = 1;
    int c = getchar();
    while (repeat)
    {
    
        if(c == '.')
        {
            putchar('\n');
            repeat = 0;
        }
        if (c == '\t'|| ispunct(c)|| c == ' ')
        {
            putchar('\n');
            c = getchar();
            while(c == '\n'||c == '\t'|| ispunct(c)|| c == ' ')
            {
                c = getchar();
            }
        }
        else
        {
         putchar(c);
         c = getchar();
        }
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGnO6.png

Comment: another else because '.' ispunct.

Comment: What info did you debugging yield? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Quentins idea seems plausible and should have been visible to you while stepping through your code.

Comment: Below is the original text so you can compare. It's printing extra lines after commas and semicolons but only when they're at the end of a line. I typed "\n" where a new line would begin in the original poem.                                                                                                                            The Parsnip\n


The parsnip, children, I repeat,\n
Is  simply an anemic beet,\n
Some people call the parsnip edible;\n
Myself,  I find this claim incredible.\n